# Number of positive $n$ s.t. $5|n^4 + 5n^2 + 9$

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility

Find the total number of positive integers $n$ not more than $2013$ such that $n^4 + 5n^2 + 9$ is divisible by $5$. This problem was taken from Singapore Math Olympiad 2013, Open Section, First round.

I tried dividing the expression by $5$ to get

$$\begin{align}\frac{n^2 + 5n^2 + 9}{5} &= n^2 + 2 + \frac{n^4-1}{5}\\
&= n^2 + 2 + \frac{(n^2 + 1)(n+1)(n-1)}{5}\end{align}$$

I then counted the number of $n$ for which either of $n^2 +1, n+1,n-1$ is divisible by $5$.

What I would like to know is, is there a simpler method to do this (without a calculator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle n^4+5n^2+9\equiv n^4-1\pmod5$

So, we need $\displaystyle n^4\equiv1\pmod5\implies (n,5)=1$

Now using Fermat's Little Theorem, $$n^4\equiv1\pmod5\text{ for } (n,5)=1$$

So, we need to find the number of positive integers $n\not>2013$ those are relatively prime with $5$

Now as $5$ is prime, either $(n,5)=1$ or $5|n$

Can you calculate how many positive integers $n\not>2013$ are divisible by $5$

Comment: @YiyuanLee, thanks